# unique value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, unique-constraint

I'm new to oracle and I am doing simple exercises to broaden my knowledge
I think I did every step successfully besides one.

The question was:

Create a table called Bank, which include following fields: Bank_id which is a number and has length of 5 and is primary key
bank_name which is a string with length of 5 and may not be empty  and Bank_Address which is a string, has length of 20 and is unique
Here's what I wrote

```
CREATE TABLE Bank
{
Bank_id number(5) primary key,
Bank_name varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 bank_address varchar(20)

}
```

My question is following
How do I declare something as unique? and is rest of my assignment correct?
I'm asking you this because I am not able to view correct answer for few days and I'm anxious to know if I did this correctly, excuse my English and thanks.

Comment: You might want to read the Oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_objects.htm#TDDDG32200

Comment: Oracle recommends using `varchar2` instead of `varchar` for strings.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that mind, thank you a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `unique constraint` for the field `bank_address` to be unique like

```
CONSTRAINT bnk_addr UNIQUE (bank_address)
```

With that your `CREATE TABLE` statement should look like

```
CREATE TABLE Bank
(
Bank_id number(5) primary key,
Bank_name varchar(5) NOT NULL,
bank_address varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT bnk_addr UNIQUE (bank_address)
);
```

Comment: @user3550204, consider accepting the answer if you have found it helpful.